# もっとわきをしめて。インパクトの瞬間に力を集中させる。 Relating to JP sword art. What does this mean?

Tags: grammar, translation, japanese-to-english, video-games

Context: MC is giving advice about sword practice to a young knight.
It seems that MC practiced JP sword art "kendo" back when he was still in his original world.

> もっとわきをしめて。インパクトの瞬間に力を集中させる。

My translation: "Put more force to the armpit. Concentrate your power at the moment of impact"

If my TL is wrong please give me your English translation. I don't know much about kendo.

Answer (score 3):

締める{しめる} here means to move or tighten the upper arms to the body. "Put more force to the armpit" doesn't really work here, because in English "put/apply force to the armpits" would mean something different. To me it means something or someone else applies force to a person's armpits.

Although 脇{わき} does mean armpit, I think here it refers to area around the armpits. The actual movement involves the back and shoulder muscles.

The opposite of 脇を締める would be 脇が開く or 脇を開ける, to relax your shoulder and back muscles so there is a space between your upper arms and your body.

> もっと脇を締めて
> Tighten up your upper arms more and move them closer to your body.

Your second sentence sounds fine to me.